# Can this while be converted to a set based query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have this query:

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempA') is not null drop table #tempA

create table #tempA
(
    tempid varchar(5),
    tempdate smalldatetime
)

declare @loopdate smalldatetime
set @loopdate = '4/2/2013'

while (@loopdate <= '4/28/2013')
begin
    --Purpose is to get IDs not in TableB for each date period
    insert into #tempA (tempid, tempdate)
    select storeid, @loopdate
    from
    (
        select tableAid
        from tableA
        except
        select tableBid
        from tableB
        where tableBdate = @loopdate
    ) as idget

    set @loopdate = DATEADD(day, 1, @loopdate)
end
```

Is there a way to make the while loop set-based or is this best that could be done?

EDIT: made changes for correctness

EDIT: end result

```
ID1 4/2/2014
ID2 4/2/2014
ID4 4/2/2014
ID2 4/3/2014
ID1 4/4/2014
ID5 4/4/2014
ID3 4/5/2014
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it can be, but can you post and example of your source data and the desired end result?

Comment: You are not inserting a value for tempdate.  That does not work.

Comment: How you are doing it may be the best way.  A set solution would need to generate that set of dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still a loop but maybe a little more efficient

```
while (@loopdate <= '4/28/2013')
begin
    --Purpose is to get IDs not in TableB for each date period
    insert into #tempA (tempid, tempdate)
    select storeid, @loopdate
    from
    (
        select tableAid
          from tableA
          left join tableB 
            on tableB.tableBid = tableA.tableAid
           and tableB.tableBdate = @loopdate 
         where tableB.tableBid is null
    ) as idget

    set @loopdate = DATEADD(day, 1, @loopdate)
end
```

This needs some work but may get you all the way with a set

```
;WITH Days
as
(
    SELECT cast('4/2/2013' AS datetime ) as 'Day'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, +1, Day) as 'Day'
      FROM Days
     where [DAY] <= '4/28/2013'
)
SELECT tableA.tableAid, Days.[Day] 
  from Days 
  left join tableB 
    on tableB.tableBdate = Days.[Day]
  full join tableA 
    on tableB.tableBid = tableA.tableAid 
 where tableB.tableBid is null
```

Comment: Is a left join really more efficient than an Except? Just wondering.

Comment: @dotnetN00b can an Except use an index?

Answer (score 1):

it depends on whether not tableA has a date on it, if not then:

```
WITH DateList(DateDay) AS 
(  
     SELECT CAST('2013-04-28' AS DATETIME)
        UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY,0,DATEADD(DAY, -1, DateDay)),0)  
    FROM DateList  
    WHERE DateDay between '2013-04-03' and '2013-04-28'
)  
SELECT DISTINCT
    tableAid
    , DateDay 
FROM DateList
  cross join #tableA a
  left join #tableB b
    on tableAid = b.tableBid
    and b.tableBdate = DateDay
where
    b.tableBid is null
ORDER BY
    DateDay ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into #tempA (tempid, tempdate)
select tableAid, tableAdate
from tableA
except
select tableBid,tableBdate
from tableB
where tableBdate >= '4/2/2013' and tableBdate <= '4/28/2013';
```

Answer (score -1):

You can include the range of dates in a conditional clause, as below:

```
insert into #tempA (tempid, tempdate)
select tableAid
from tableA
except
select tableBid
from tableB
where tableBdate >= '4/2/2013' and tableBdate <= '4/28/2013';
```